# htaccess rewrite rules specific to uri

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Block hidden directories
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

    # Prevent /health_check.php from using https
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(health_check\.php)$

    # Prevent /sns from using https but this DOES need codeigniter rewriting (see below)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sns)/

    # Reroute http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Prevent rewriting of domain for codeigniter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

What I am trying to do is

- Rewrite codeigniter urls (including /sns)
- Forward http requests to https (except for /health_check.php and /sns)
- Block hidden directories

This all seems to be working except /sns still forwards to https and changes to /index.php/sns

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd rule to this:

```
# Prevent /health_check.php from using https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/health_check\.php [NC]

# Prevent /sns from using https but this DOES need codeigniter rewriting (see below)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/sns [NC]

# Reroute http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

- Using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as last rule will change `REQUEST_URI` to `/index.php`.
- Make sure to test this in a new browser.

Comment: ok try my updated rule in a new browser. Also make sure there is not separate .htaccess in `sns` directory or anywhere else.

Comment: Still redirecting to https... could it be because of the CI rewrite rule? Do I need to exclude /index.php/sns too?

Comment: On my apache exact same rule with same URL is not redirecting to `https://` so it is not rule but something else in your local code/config causing this.

Comment: Note that you don't need to exclude `index.php` because we are using `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original Apache request.

Comment: Yes space is needed because `^` is a regex that means match everything and part with `https://....` is target.

Comment: One more thing you can do is to enable `RewriteLog` and then check logs to see what rule is triggering this.